# how set integer field fix length

Tags: integer, field

lass Bill_pass(models.Model):
    party_code=models.ForeignKey('Suppmast',default =autonum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    party_name=Suppmast('party_name')
    bill_no=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    bill_date=models.DateField()
    bill_amt=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
    material=models.TextField()
    gsttype=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    gstamt=models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    bill_pass_dt=models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

Comment: I edited your question a bit, but you should add a language to the tags

Comment: Hey @jnt, welcome. We won't be able to help with this unless you provide more context, so could you please update your question to include the following:
* What language are you working with? (e.g. java)
* What is a high level description of what you're trying to do? (e.g. i'm trying to trim integers to 20 chars in order to make the display more readable to users).
* What have you tried, and with what results? (e.g. I've tried using these functions, but they had no effect on the display.)
Also, please add markdown (by indenting with 4 spaces) when posting code in your question.